# multiple Or conditions vs several individual JPQ/Hibernate queries - on entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, entity

I need to query database for different combination of elements from the already received result object.

For instance, I get a list of `Person` entities. For each person in Person entities, I need to get List of address (for each person).

There are two ways to do it:

1. Iterate the Person entity and fire a query for each Person entity to get the list of Addresses for that person.
2. Build a query dynamically with elements from Person entity and fire ONE single query to pull all addresses lists for all Persons and then iterate the Person entity again and match the Address list for each Person.

I don't know much many Person entities I might get. So what is the better approach in terms of performance and practice.

So, if I have 100 Person entities, in the first approach its going to be 100 queries vs 2nd approach with huge query like below

```
 from address where  (person.id = 1 and person.zip = 393)
                  or (person.id = 2 and person.zip = 123)
                  or (person.id = 3 and person.zip = 345)
                  .... // 10 times.
```

Which one is better? Any restrictions / limitation on Or conditions in Oracle?
Is there a better approach? Batch queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate with eager loading to directly get the results what you want by loading the person with the restrictions required. Or else if you want to stick to lazy loading try using an inner join with person and Address so that you can then get a list of array which consist the results

Comment: May be I was not clear in my question. I cannot linke Person with Address. I must iterate the Person entties to get address for each Person. The question is One single query or multiple queries